# Getting distance between zipcode (pyzipcode)

Tags: django

Using pyzipcode (django python package), I'm able to get the zip codes within a radius of another zipcode (local_zip) using the code below.

```
in_radius = [z.zip for z in zcdb.get_zipcodes_around_radius(local_zip, 10)]
objects_output = Model.objects.filter(Q(zipcode__in=10)).distinct()
```

I am able to find all the zipcode in let's say 10 miles of a chosen zipcode (local_zip), but I want the know the exact mileage difference.

This would be the desired output:

```
zipcode, miles
90101, 8 
90210, 3
90211, 4
...  ,...
90234, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looping over the results and getting the lat, long.

```
from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
import geopy.distance
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()

local_zip = 76244
in_radius = [z.zip for z in zcdb.get_zipcodes_around_radius(local_zip, 10)]


zip1 = zcdb[local_zip]
coords_1 =(zip1.latitude, zip1.longitude)
    
for zip in in_radius:
    zip2 = zcdb[zip]
    coords_2 =(zip2.latitude, zip2.longitude)

    miles_between = round(geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).miles, 1)

    print("{0}, {1}".format(zip, miles_between))
```